# Woocommerce product permalink and image query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this bit of code that I found to create a custom email...

```
function get_order_details($order_id){

    // 1) Get the Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // OUTPUT

    echo '<h1>LIKE IT? LOVE IT? LET US KNOW!</h1>';
    echo '<br>';

    // 2) Get the Order meta data
    $order_meta = get_post_meta($order_id);

    echo '' . $order_meta[_billing_first_name][0] . ", the more you share, the more you help other customers. We would love to know your thoughts on your most recent purchase and we'd appreciate it if you could take a moment to write a quick review";
    echo '<br><hr><br>';

    // 3) Get the order items
    $items = $order->get_items();

 foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) {
    $product       = $item->get_product();
    $image         = $product->get_image(array( 100, 100 ));

    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', $image, $item ) );
    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item->get_name(), $item, false ) );   
}
    echo '<br><hr><br>';

}
```

Can someone please tell me what I would add to get the product url to display?
(I want to have it in a 'Review now' box - not actually display)
Thanks!

Comment: Try this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277465/getting-the-gallery-images-from-products-in-woocommerce/311359#311359

Comment: I don't understand which bits of this code to use or how to tie it back into my original code

Comment: Okay i've added the image, thank you! Do you know how i'd add the product url? Thanks!

Comment: You have Product id ??

Comment: I've updated the code above. Not sure how to get product ID from it

Comment: Try to use this echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($product_id).'">'.get_the_title($product_id).'</a>';

Comment: That wants to display the order details, not the actual product page - this is what it returns - https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/?post_type=shop_order&p=3527

Comment: Page not working check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187182/discussion-between-harsh-khare-and-michelle).

Comment: I know.. it doesn't take you to the correct page... and the page it does take you to doesn't exist